# How do I exclude certain columns within a transformation?

Tags: upsolver

When using Upsolver SQLake, if my source table has 100's of columns, and I want to include most of them in a transformation, but exclude a few, can I do that without having to explicitly map every column in the transformation SQL?

For example, if my source table has 5 columns, (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5), and in my transformation I do not want to include col3.  I could use the following SQL:

SELECT col1, col2, col4, col5 FROM sourcetable

However, if my source table has 1000 columns, I'd rather not have to type out 999 columns if I don't have to.

I was looking for an option to generate SQL, or some option to exclude certain columns from a transformation.

Answer (score 0):

SQLake supports an EXCEPT parameter in the transformation job definition.  The transformation SQL will be evaluated, however columns in the EXCEPT reference will be excluded in the target table.

```
CREATE JOB insert_all_columns_except_col3
    START_FROM = NOW
    ADD_MISSING_COLUMNS = TRUE
    RUN_INTERVAL = 1 MINUTE
AS INSERT INTO target_table MAP_COLUMNS_BY_NAME EXCEPT col3
SELECT *
FROM source_table
WHERE $commit_time BETWEEN RUN_START_TIME() and RUN_END_TIME();
```

In this case, all columns from "source_table" will be written into "target_table" except for col3.